# How to get the "style" from a classic textField when loaded by code?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, fonts, styles, textfield

I need to get the style used in a textField placed in the stage, and doing this by code.

The thing is, bold and italic are not enough in my case, since I have a style that is semi-bold.

And I can't find the way to get that style when I analyze the textField in my code.

Do you know of any way to do this?.

In other words, I need to know what is the style of the font used in Flash when I get the textFormat.

For example, if I have a font that is "Signika", I need to know that the style is Semibold. Right now, I only get "Signika". It works if I check the bold style, becuase bold is true. But thats all the information I can get from it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behold [TextField API Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html) and the [`getTextFormat()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#getTextFormat%28%29) method.  *(yay!)*

It returns a [`TextFormat`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextFormat.html) object which contains a complete definition of that TextField, which can then be applied to another TextField via [`setTextFormat()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#setTextFormat%28%29).

That said, font families work a little differently in AS3 (sadly, not Adobe's fault, but rather the OS).  For example, Myriad Pro has Regular, Light, Semibold, and Bold.  Yet, once embedded, only two actual font names are displayed, and the only way to differentiate them is by setting the `TextFormat.bold = true`.

[image: The problem with getting font families in flash.]

Interestingly, omitting the embed of one of these companion fonts will not throw an error, but rather, in the case that you were to embed only Myriad Pro Regular and not Myriad Pro Bold, setting the `TextFormat.bold = true` will perform faux bold on regular (which will naturally be much lower quality than the actual bold font, but... it works).

Hope that clears things up.

---

**Update**

I looked into the Signika, and it apparently suffers from an acute identity crisis.  To exemplify this, embed the entire font family and run the following:

```
var fontList:Array = Font.enumerateFonts();
for( var i:int = 0; i < fontList.length; i++ ) {
    trace("Font Name: " + fontList[i].fontName + ", " + fontList[i].fontStyle )
}
```

This will trace a list of each font that's present in the environment.  Sadly, regardless of how you embed the font (programmatically, or via library import), the font overwrites other family entries (hypothetically because they report the same way without distinction to the environment).

```
// Myriad Pro Results:
Font Name: Myriad Pro, regular
Font Name: Myriad Pro, bold
Font Name: Myriad Pro Light, regular
Font Name: Myriad Pro Light, bold
```

Running the same query against a the Myriad Pro family actually reports four entries, without overlap, whereas Signika will only report 2 of 4.

```
// Signika Results:
Font Name: Signika, regular
Font Name: Signika, bold
```

What I stated previously still stands: using the API methods above will result in a `TextFormat` object that fully describes the fonts in use.  These are distinguished by both `name:String`, and `bold:Boolean` properties on the object.  However, since Flash overwrites the embedded object with the same reported properties (or simply doesn't overwrite), you only have 2 of the 4 family styles available at any time: a regular version, and a bold version.

Hope that clarifies things.

Comment: I'm using the getTextFormat method. But it doesn't tell me what is the style. Actually, there is no style property, or anything like that. Btw, I embed the fonts, always, otherwise I get crappy results in terms of sharpness. Am I missing something?.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "style".  `getTextFormat` returns an object with the following properties: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextFormat.html.  You can use that same object and apply it to a new TextField and replicate the appearance.  As you see from the example given above, there is no reference to "Semibold" in the properties of that particular font, and actually shows up as "Myriad Pro Light" with `TextFormat.bold = true`, but it is Myriad Pro Semibold, and that's how you define it programmatically.

Comment: With respect to the "crappy results in terms of sharpness", you can turn on Anti-Aliasing to improve legibility with `antiAliasType` property (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#antiAliasType).  Simply do `myTextField.antiAliasType = flash.text.AntiAliasType.ADVANCED`

Comment: With Style I'm talking about the style tab in Flash Pro. In Flash Pro you have the fonts family tab, and just below that you have a style tab. The style tab has different options. Bold, regular, italic, and sometimes, it has options that are not present in the textFormat class, for example, semi-bold. When that happens, I couldn't find a way to retrieve it, and replicate it. Because using getTextFormat() I only get: font: Signika, bold: false. That's all.

Comment: We're talking about the same issue.  See the updated explanation above.  That said, semibold appears to report the same way as Signika regular which is a problem with the way the font family was authored.  You could try editing the font in something like FontLab to give each font a unique name.

Comment: I see. Thank your for taking the time for this. I ended up with a not very cool solution. I added a _style_ in the textField name in Flash, and I asked for it in the code. If name.indexOf() style != -1, Y check the style, if not, I use the textFormat font and bold.